# Передача файла по SFTP

Tags: php, sftp

Есть 2 сервера. Один с поддержкой PHP, другой нет. Значит передать файл по API не получится. Поэтому как передать загружаемый пользователем файл с одного сервера на другое по SFTP?

Comment: функция `ssh2_scp_send` - такой вариант не подойдет?

Comment: Интересует именно SFTP. При загрузке файл обрабатывается и сохраняется на 1 сервер, после сохранения его нужно передать именно по SFTP на второй сервер

Comment: @Евгения пробовали так искать https://packagist.org/?query=sftp или хотя бы так  https://www.google.com/search?q=php+sftp ?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php